# Exception in thread "main" org.renjin.eval.EvalException: Could not resolve native method 'dplyr_combine_vars' in package 'dplyr'

Tags: renjin

I am getting following error when running R through renjin , can someone help me 
I am using following packages

library(dplyr)
 library(downloader)

when I run through R studio it works fine but not through renjin.  I can put more details about version I am using

```
INFO: Using "C:\Users\ukhan\AppData\Local\Temp\vfs_cache" as temporary files store.
Exception in thread "main" org.renjin.eval.EvalException: Could not resolve native method 'dplyr_combine_vars' in package 'dplyr'
    at org.renjin.primitives.Native.findMethodByName(Native.java:574)
    at org.renjin.primitives.Native.findMethod(Native.java:547)
    at org.renjin.primitives.Native.redotCall(Native.java:363)
    at org.renjin.primitives.R$primitive$$Call.apply(R$primitive$$Call.java:62)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluateCall(Context.java:407)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:282)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:264)
    at org.renjin.primitives.special.BeginFunction.apply(BeginFunction.java:38)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluateCall(Context.java:407)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:282)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:264)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:198)
    at org.renjin.sexp.Closure.doApply(Closure.java:98)
    at org.renjin.eval.ClosureDispatcher.apply(ClosureDispatcher.java:80)
    at org.renjin.eval.ClosureDispatcher.applyClosure(ClosureDispatcher.java:51)
    at org.renjin.sexp.Closure.apply(Closure.java:83)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluateCall(Context.java:407)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:282)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:264)
    at org.renjin.primitives.special.AssignLeftFunction.assignLeft(AssignLeftFunction.java:57)
    at org.renjin.primitives.special.AssignLeftFunction.apply(AssignLeftFunction.java:41)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluateCall(Context.java:407)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:282)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:264)
    at org.renjin.primitives.special.BeginFunction.apply(BeginFunction.java:38)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluateCall(Context.java:407)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:282)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:264)
    at org.renjin.eval.Context.evaluate(Context.java:198)
    at org.renjin.sexp.Closure.doApply(Closure.java:98)
    at org.renjin.eval.ClosureDispatcher.apply(ClosureDispatcher.java:80)
    at
```

Answer (score 0):

As your code has not been submitted I am writing based on 2 assumptions : 1) you are using Maven as your dependency management tool and 2) you have only included Renjin as a project dependency

In this case I would guess your POM file is missing the lines in the link below : http://packages.renjin.org/package/org.renjin.cran/dplyr/0.7.4

If, however, the dependency is already set I assume the error above happens because the Renjin implementation of this package (as explained in the link above) is still not fully functional. From what I've seen most of the packages that are highly dependent on C/C++ code take more time to be fully functional than pure R packages - one example is the Forecast package that has taken about 2 years to be somewhat usable.